# It's possible to use multiple value in single enumeration tag?

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation

I'm using XSD validation in WEB API project.

now i'm using following method for check string value.

```
 <xs:simpleType name="CoverageTierPattern">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
  <xs:enumeration value="EE"/>
  <xs:enumeration value="ES"/>
  <xs:enumeration value="EC"/>
  <xs:enumeration value="Fam"/>
  <xs:enumeration value="WO"/>
  <xs:enumeration value="WP"/>
  <xs:enumeration value="NE"/>
  <xs:enumeration value="RC"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

this list value must be added more in future.

So i need to know it's possible to use values in single enumeration element

like

```
 <xs:enumeration value="EE|ES|EC|..."/>
```

other wise if any other method present plz tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pattern` element instead of `enumeration` like this:

```
 <xs:pattern value="EE|ES|EC|..."/>
```

Full example from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_facets.asp) in the middle of the page.

```
<xs:element name="gender">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="male|female"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```